# Calling Activity.finish always recreates previous activity on Back Stack

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Inside one of my activity's callback method for an http request, I do this:

```
public void dataReceivedSuccessfully(String data) {
    Form[] forms = getFormsFromJson(data);
    final FormListAdapter adapter = new FormListAdapter(forms, this);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            gvForms.setAdapter(adapter);
            pbForms.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            gvForms.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // <-- this is the issue

            finish(); // <-- this causes previous activity to recreate itself
            new Timer().schedule(() -> { finish(); }, 1000); // <-- this works!
            new Timer().schedule(() -> { finish(); }, 10); // <-- this works 90% of time!
        }
    });
}
```

So it seems that if time duration between line commented `this is the issue` and call of `finish` is much less for android's liking, it recreates the previous activity. On that line, I am simply making a `GridView` visible to user after filling it with data. Please note that this is a sample scenario and I know user won't have time to see data in that view.

How can I overcome this? And what precisely is going on here?

Answer (score -1):

Read [Managing the Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) and [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) to understand default back naviagtion implementation.

Comment: It does not explain my situation here. I looked at Android's source code and saw that onBackPressed calls the finish method which I'm doing too. The point here is that it does not recreate the previous activity on back stack if you call it after a little delay.

Comment: Can you elaborate what functionality you want to implement or what issue you are facing ?

Comment: Activity A starts activity B. Activity B sends an HTTP request. When activity B receives HTTP response, it calls its `finish` method to go back to previous activity on back stack. Activity A comes to front but gets recreated, i.e., onDestroy and then onCreate is called. I don't want activity A to be recreated here, there is a lot of RAM available and no other apps running. If I remove the `finish` call from activity B and press the back button manually after HTTP response is received, it works as I expect, i.e., activity A simply comes in front without getting recreated.